# Test whether at least one directory with a name prefix exists in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script with a user-entered name, and want to determine whether any directories exist starting with that name.

This code looks like:

```
runTest() {
  if test -d "$name"*; then
    echo "Directories starting with $name already exist"
  fi
}
```

It works fine if there is only one such directory:

```
name=foobar
rm -rf foobar*
mkdir foobar1
runTest # now the code will work
```

...but it *doesn't* work if there are multiple matches:

```
name=foobar
rm -rf foobar*
mkdir foobar1 foobar2
runTest # now the code will emit an error: "test: too many arguments"
```

How can I make this work with any number of directories, without assuming that one of the matches will always include a specific number (like `1`)?

Comment: `test -d` can't check multiple arguments. `test -d "$name"*` stands a chance of attempting to do so if the argument expands into more than one name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example of a working (bash-only -- not `/bin/sh` compatible) alternative, consider:

```
if dirs=( "$name"*/ ) && [[ -d ${dirs[0]} ]]; then
  echo "Directories starting with $name already exist"
fi
```

- An array assignment works with any number of matches
- ...but the first entry in the array will be a valid directory only if the glob successfully expanded (and the trailing `/` in the glob expression prevents it from expanding to anything *except* directories, so if the result has any directories at all, you know that *all* elements it expanded to are directories).

---

If you need something that works for `/bin/sh` as well, consider the following function:

```
directoriesExist() { [ -d "$1" ]; }
if directoriesExist "$name"*/;  then
  echo "Directories starting with $name already exist"
fi
```

This works because the list of matches expands onto the function's argument list, effectively serving as an alternative to an array.

---

Because `[` is a shell builtin, these globbing-based approaches have much lower constant-factor costs than approaches depending on external tools, which will make them considerably faster overall (except for some corner cases, such as directories so large that it's preferable to stop after the first match is found; where `find . -name "$name*" -print -quit` may be useful).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one.

```
#! /bin/bash -e
name='foobar'

if [ `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$name*" -print -quit` -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "Directories starting with $name already exist"
fi
```

Comment: This is **really** needlessly inefficient (and also doesn't work with any names that don't expand to a single argument to grep, or where that argument isn't a regex that matches itself as a substring). Command substitution requires `fork()`ing a  subshell, and then you're creating a pipeline of three external processes (each of which is another `fork()` and an `execve()`, not to mention requiring the creation of a FIFO pair). `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$name*" -print -quit` would at least make the search stop when a match is found, rather than continuing to look for more files.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
ls "$name"*/ >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Directories starting with $name already exist"
```

(caution: may not work in some special cases (special characters in file names etc))

Comment: When you run `ls "$name"*`, the shell itself expands `"$name"*`  *before `ls` is even started*. All the expense of linking and loading an external binary when the work you really want (expanding the list of names) is already complete is a bit silly.

Comment: yeah, but it's very short, portable and easy to remember